# Magic __call method in abstract superclass

Tags: php, magic-methods

This question is related to this other question: [PHP's magic method __call on subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535180/phps-magic-method-call-on-subclasses), but I'm not satisfied with the accepted answer.

What I'm trying to do is implement a generic way to create method aliases, without having to define a named function for every alias, using the magic `__call` method.

This system would use an associative array as a lookup table in the form of `"alias" => "actualMethod`.

```
abstract class Super {

    private $aliases;

    protected function __construct(array $aliases) {
        $this->aliases = $aliases;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {

        /* if $name is an alias, replace it */
        if (isset($this->aliases[$name])) {
            $name = $this->aliases[$name];
        }

        /* throw an exception if the method is undefined */
        if (!method_exists($this, $name)) {
            throw new Exception("The specified method or method alias is undefined in the current context");
        }

        /* finally, call the method by its actual name */
        return $this->$name($arguments);
    }

}
```

The problem seems to be that either me or the PHP guys don't understand polymorphism.

```
class Sub extends Super {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(array(
            "alias" => "actualMethod"
        ));
    }

    private function actualMethod() {
        echo "Inside the actual method";
    }

}
```

When I define the `__call` method on an abstract class, then define the `actualMethod` on a subclass, PHP enters an infinite recursion loop inside `__call` when I try to invoke the `actualMethod` by its `alias`.

```
try {
    $object = new Sub();
    $object->alias(); /* causes infinite __call recursion inside Super */
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
}
```

This is funny, because the call to `method_exists` inside `__call` returns **TRUE**.

Surely I can't be the first person to notice this behavior, right? What's the deal here?

**EDIT**

So basically, normal inheritance rules don't apply for magic methods? It seems that I can't call private methods further down the inheritance tree from inside `__call()` (*). However I can still call private methods if they are defined in the same class.

(*): even though `__call` is public, and the object is an instance of the subclass where the private method is defined.

How does that work exactly?

Comment: The example code given here [seems to work fine, as shown in this online evaluator](http://3v4l.org/rkEs5).

Comment: What the... I don't know how that's possible. The only thing I can think of is that my real code is using namespaces while the examples are not.

Comment: I cracked the case. My actual methods are `private`, so for whatever reason they are invisible to whatever mechanism is responsible for triggering `__call`.

You can verify this behavior by changing the scope of `actualMethod` to private. The fix/hack from my answer still works. I don't know if the bug in this case is that the problem exists or that a workaround exists. Food for thought.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense - and goes to show that you should always test any simplified examples before you post them. If a method is `private` in `Sub`, then it is invisible to `Super` - `private` scopes to the current *class*, not the current *object*.

Comment: Then shouldn't `method_exists()` in `Super` return false?

Comment: `method_exists` doesn't take visibility into account, it literally asks whether the method, um, exists. You could maybe use `is_callable`.

Comment: Okay, it's all starting to click now. But still, the solution in my answer works even though `actualMethod` is being called from the outside. Shouldn't PHP prevent this? EDIT: I guess not because I placed `__call` within the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is weird - I don't have an answer to *why*, but a workaround for your problem could be:

```
    /* finally, call the method by its actual name */
    return call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $arguments);
```

Comment: Same problem. My code always goes straight back to `__call` instead of checking whether the method exists inside `Sub`. Very frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a way to do it. I'm not sure if it is *the* way to do it or just a dirty hack. Anyway:

```
class Sub extends Super {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(array(
            "alias" => "actualMethod"
        ));
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if (!method_exists($this, $name)) {
            return parent::__call($name, $arguments);
        }
        return $this->$name($arguments);
    }

    private function actualMethod() {
        echo "Inside the actual method";
    }

}
```

This works by only calling the `__call` method inside `Sub` if the specified method does not exist already in either `Sub` or `Super`. When it doesn't, the `Sub::__call()` is invoked, which in turn invokes `Super::__call`. The result is that either an exception is thrown, or control is handed back to `Sub::__call` which then invokes the `actualMethod()`.

I hope that made sense.

**EDIT**

I completely forgot to add `return` keywords in my examples. Obviously these are crucial if you're trying to return anything other than void.

Comment: By definition, `method_exists($this, $name)` will never return `true` at the very top of that `__call` method, as `__call` is only called if the method *doesn't* exist.

Comment: You are partially right. The check is pointless on the first time (when `$name=="alias"`), but the `parent::__call()` will result in `__call` being triggered again. Only this time, `$name=="actualMethod"`. If that sounds weird to you, it's because it should. I'm pretty damn sure by now that this is a bug.